# How do I restructure the document.ready function to allow for the button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery function which would get the current position and use an API to request the current weather condition. I have it inside the document.ready() function so that the page loads to display the current location. I also have a .click() function for a button which takes in a city name and does another api request. However, after the API call the page reloads again resulting in the first API call again. I don't understand how to restructure the function such that their execution is isolated. Here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(data) {
      var lat = data.coords.latitude;
      var lon = data.coords.longitude;
      console.log(lat);
      console.log(lon);
      var weatherUrl = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=" + lat + "&lon=" + lon + "&units=metric";
      extractVals(weatherUrl);
    });
  } else {
    alert("Geolocation is not supported. Enter your zip code!");
  }

  $("#formSubmit").click(function() {
    btnClicked = true;
    var cityName = $("#cityText").val();
    console.log(cityName);

    if (cityName) {
      var weatherUrl = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + cityName + "&units=metric";
    } else {
      alert("Pease enter a valid city name");
    }

    extractVals(weatherUrl);
  });

});
```

Any pointers? Thanks.

Edit: I have included the html code:

```
<form>
  <input  type="text" class="form-control" id="cityText" name="city" placeholder="Enter your city"><br>
  <button type="button" id="formSubmit" onclick="submitBtn(event);">Submit</button> 
</form>
```

Comment: It's important to show the HTML the code is working with as well.

Comment: I have included the html in the edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't shown your HTML, but I'm going to guess that `#formSubmit` is a `type="submit"` button (note that that's the default type of `button` elements).

Clicking a submit button submits the form, making it load the result of the form in the page. If you don't want the button to do that, make it a `type="button"` button or use `preventDefault` (or `return false`) in your handler.

Answer (score -2):

You need to use .on() for click function. This will work whenever content changes.
please note may you need use **classname** instead of **ID**.

here is sample:

```
$( document ).on( "click", "#formSubmit", function() {
  console.log( 'Button Clicked' );
});
```

Comment: There's no indication in the question that the `#formSubmit` button is being destroyed and recreated.